# Can I use my Windows 7 to OS X emulator to upload binary

Tags: ios, windows-7

I don't want to buy a Mac to upload my iOS binary to iTunes using Application loader.  Is there a way to use an emulator to do this?

Comment: Your question isn't easy to be understood. What are you trying to do? Perhaps you want to share an application you made in the App Store?

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: @bdukes Yes, but he doesn't have the rep to allow him to comment yet.

Comment: I'm trying to upload a binary for inclusion in the App Store.  As far as I understood it, you can't use the PC version of iTunes Connect to load binaries anymore.  It can only be done using application loader which is only available on the OS X

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the answer is **no**. You have to use the relevant version of Xcode for the iOS you want to upload to. So for example iOS7 requires Xcode 5. This is because before you can upload the binary you must first archive it and then validate it. This validation is a quick Apple check on your binary to ensure nothing is wrong with it. You must then code sign it with your distribution certificates. As far as I'm aware there are no emulators on windows that can do this.